# How to get fan list of Facebook page or can overwrite facebook social plugin css?

Tags: java, gwt, facebook

We are trying it with facebook social  plugin. The HTML code for it as follow:

> <iframe border='0' src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=1185611481&width=243&height=400&connections=15&stream=false&header=false' scrolling='yes' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='false' style='border:0px; overflow:hidden; width:243px; height:300px; background-color: #03869E; color: white;'> <iframe>

As it replace inner HTML of frame on load. We want our own CSS to apply to this HTML. But as it replace whole HTML and it have its own CSS we are unable to set our CSS.

We are doing this in GWT. Is there any way we can get the list of fans so we can display it as we want and can apply css? Or check given user is fan of page?

Comment: a similar question has been asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001281/retrieve-facebook-fan-names

Answer (score 0):

you can try, css insertion using javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "style.css"

var myframe = frames["your-frame"].document;
frame.head.appendChild(link);

</script>
```