# Where are likes from the LIKE button stored and how to get them using FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

There seem to be many many unanswered questions about this. Hopefully, I'll get lucky with this one :)

When someone clicks "Like" on a particular page, a post shows up in their stream that says "xxxxxx likes a link" along with data about that link. How can I use FQL to get this data -

1. For the logged in user

2. For friends of the logged in user

**NOTE:** 

1. I am not talking about facebook pages (in which case you become a "fan"). I know that you can access this with the `page_fan` table or even the `connection` table.


2. One of the many issues seems to be that you cannot query the `like` table for anyone but the current user. (Graph API for like gives you a list of FAN PAGES - not what I want)

3. Even if you query the `like` table for the current user, you only get a list of posts/videos shared by friends that have been liked by the current user. Not pages outside facebook.

3. I can get shared links by looking at the `link` table. But I want the list of pages where a user has clicked "Like" or "Recommend" using the facebook like button for the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest

Comment: The short answer from the above duplicate is: you can't get any info about friends who have liked particular items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the `url_like` FQL table with your user ID. For example: `SELECT url from url_like where user_id = me()`.

You can do this for friends of the current user as well. See the FQL url_like table [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/) for details.

Comment: Wait, was that table there all along? I just feel plain stupid not having seen that before! Anyway, thanks a lot! 

One question though. This does not work. Seems to be taking forever.
`select url from url_like where user_id in (select uid1 from friend where uid2 = me()) limit 50`

Comment: I think it's a relatively new table. Not sure why you're seeing the long wait; I'm getting an error myself, so I'll look into this. The simple query that I posted does work for me, though.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly when I ask for me() or for a specific friend. Thanks for checking up on this for multiple friends (with a limit of course)

Comment: It appears to be a bug. I've filed it.