# FLinq on a Page

Tags: c#, facebook-fql

I normally work on C# but could understand other languages.

I'm pretty much trying to retrieve the list of people that LIKE my Facebook Page
where I am an Admin.

So what is the easiest way to do so ?
Remember I tend to use C# as the programming language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, read the answer from Jonathan Dean at [How to list facebook users who like a page or interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest)

But learning the facebook API is a good way to expand your horizons.

1. Register with facebook to become a developer.
2. Download and get some of the sample apps running from
   http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation
3. Get used to the new graph API using facebook's tool. 
   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
4. Study up on FQL and how to run it thru the new graph API.