# Get count of people who like two specific Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I know how to get the number of people who like a given page, what I'm looking for is how to get the count of people who like *two* specific pages. That is, can I get the number of people who like the pages (for example) Lady Gaga *and* Oreos? You can get the count for each very easily, but is there a way to figure out the number of people that overlap and like both? Not looking for the names or profiles, just the total count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For privacy you can't get the list of Uids for each page's likes - so there is nothing to compare as you would need a list of Uids from both pages and then see which Uid's are in both lists.

See this post for more detail: [How to list facebook users who like a page or interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest)

Comment: I figured this would be how to do it, but wasn't sure if there was some call that FB did on its end and then served up the result to you without showing you the step in between (comparing the Uids).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of likes for a page via the Graph API Explorer.  However, doing data mining like finding out the count of the number of people who overlap between the two pages is not released by Facebook.  They get a lot of income from selling data points like that, so they're not going to let that cash cow out of their corrals.

Comment: Thanks...it's definitely valuable data, but I don't think they monetize it at all. For example, they could charge a premium to allow for targeting people with ads who like a certain set of Pages, but they don't.

Comment: Trust me, there's HUGE money in data mining.  And this is one of the more basic data mining point that marketers love taking advantage of.  Marketers pay big money for data points like these.