# How to get the number of "likes" by your friends for a given place

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Given a place, like https://graph.facebook.com/112088822180423, how can I get the number of likes just by my friends? The graph gives me Likes, Checkins and Talking_About_count, but I just want whose likes by my friends. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this is possible through the use of FQL and the [page_fan table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for a page you administer and you want do this as an admin, it may not be possible with current API. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/6737579/121052, you cannot get the list of likes for a location or a page. If you had the list, you can fetch a list of your own friends, and then performed an intersection.

However, if it is a feature you are building in an App to be used by it's users - i.e you want to display the list of friends of the user who has liked a page, then that is possible. For that, do the following:

- Use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes to get if the user likes a page/location.
- Use [http://graph.facebook.com/**USER**/friends?access_token=XXX](http://graph.facebook.com/__USER__/friends?access_token=XXX) to get the list of his friends.
- For any friend, you can perform the like check again and make the intersection.

I am sure there might be a way to optimize this operation. [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) will definitely help.