# Facebook get users that like our business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our business wants to give a free gift to all the users that like our facebook page. Do you know a way to get the list of emails with all users that liked our page?

1. Is it possible to obtain that using graph API?
2. Is there any possibility to offer this functionality to our customers? My problem will reduce to check if one user likes our page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list facebook users who like a page or interest](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After much research, I used this solution:

1. I call FB.login to authorize my application and request 'user_likes' permission
2. check /me/likes/[pageid]

If the response is not null the user likes our page.

Answer (score 1):

Radu,

This is not possible at (with FB API) at this time.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest)

Answer (score 0):

You could create tab (with a canvas url) on your facebook page that does the following:

1. User clicks the tab (or is directed there by some other link)
2. On the canvas page, use the FB api to check if that user has liked your page. If not, persuade them to do so.
3. If the user liked the page, show a form where the user can enter his email.
4. Store the data on your own server.

Hope this helps.