# In Facebook, How to got "all users" who likes my post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-messages

I use Graph API Explorer to get who is like my post..
but the worst case is, if someone like my post again, the previous user will not shown again..
How can I got all the users who like my post??

I want to know all the users because I want send messages to all people who like my post..
Is that others way to do my idea?

Thanks

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)?
[Additional info if that's the case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest)

Comment: @martn I don't mean page, but user's post. When I use Graph API explorer, I can get someone ID who like my post..
The bad case is, when others people like the post, the previous ID is gone..
Can I got the all ID ?

Comment: It's similar to this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799280/how-to-get-all-people-who-liked-facebook-post/39931628#39931628

Answer (score 0):

Try graph.facebook.com/post_id/likes 
This will give you all the people who liked the post with post_id

Answer (score 0):

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/POST_ID/likes?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN`
this will give you all the users who liked your post with all there specification 
try hitting it once