# How to get all people who liked Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have FB [post](https://www.facebook.com/Eventinarea/posts/336638873112346) 
I can click "77 people like this" and get all people I needed. 
 
Question: is there way to get these people by FB API ? 
PS I want to get 3 random names from these list so I need to have these people in JSON format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do with FQL. This gets you three random ids of people who liked this event

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id = 336638873112346 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3
```

If you wanted to get their names instead, you'd rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT uid, name, username FROM user WHERE uid IN 
 (SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id = 336638873112346 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the co-founders of [Kither](https://www.kither.io), a platform for checking all of your Facebook stats. We have added many features which requires to fetch all of our user's posts likes.

[As of August 6, 2016, FQL is deprecated.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Facebook's Graph API's still available and you can call **`https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/{post-id}/likes`** to get likes on posts. But remember, Facebook uses pagination on likes if there are more than 1,000 of them.

Now, In this case you'll need to call the next page url.

[image: Facebook Likes' pagination]

You'll need to call the **next** url unless you've got all the likes. *(you won't find any **next** field if there are no more likes)*

To get how many people have liked that post (i.e. count), you don't need to page through results. You can simply use **`https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/{post-id}/likes?summary=true`** and you'll get an extra field containing all likes' summary, including their count.

Same can be done with **comments** and recently added, **reactions**.