# facebook user profiles by likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a "Like"-object data from facebook:

```
{
    "name": "24",
    "category": "Tv show",
    "id": "14176232250",
    "created_time": "2010-10-29T17:46:27+0000"
}
```

it's possible to get all users, which have that "object" in their "likes"?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve information on users who like a page via either the Graph API or FQL.

- See this previous question: [Retrieve Facebook Fan Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001281/retrieve-facebook-fan-names)