# Profile ID of page likers

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

How can I get the profile ID of the profiles who liked my page using Graph API or using FQL? I could get the number of likes from Graph API but not the list pf profiles

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve Facebook Fan Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001281/retrieve-facebook-fan-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, however, grab the profile IDs of people who have liked your most recent posts.

Like:

```
SELECT uid,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,current_location,profile_url FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT user_id from like where object_id=12121212)
```

Where 12121212 is the ID of the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to the Permission restrictions of the Facebook platform.